Can you translate this from Proto-Turkic?
The following two sentences are written in Proto-Turkic. Decipher them.
Hint:

 Proto-Turkic is also highly agglutinative and uses several suffixes to form nouns. Remember that several of these nouns are formed using suffixes plus case markings.

Kiši yaŋïlïĺ tüĺünükni kïrmaknï kǖsemeŕ. Ɨĺanuk sɨmtakniŋ edgü sēŕür.

Google translate makes funny translations to english ... Try both, try first sentence only. Try second.

Is that a puzzle?
